# How to Save Desktop icon layout position with a different profile for one or two monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, icons, desktop-customization, ultramon

i am working with a laptop at work,
now, when im sitting at the office, i use dual monitor settings, and when i work outside the office, i work with only 1 monitor.

the desktop icons are driving me crazy.
i can manage and save their position for only one scenario, and i currently save the dual monitor settings, but then when i'm out of the office, i get the icons all scrambled.

i am using ultramon, but i didnt find any way to use profiles, or save two settings.

anyone got an idea?

thanks, 
david

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.pchell.com/support/savedesktoplayout.shtml
Try the above link this should do the trick.  You will have to save the format you want then doa quick restore after using the other monitor.  Also could try keeping screen resolution same on both monitors. and or unchecking auto arrange icons.  All methods seem to work in some way.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.