# How to recover icons off right side of filled Desktop?

Tags: windows-8, desktop-icons

How do I recover these icons without

1. Sorting and thus changing the order of the existing icons on the desktop (some were removed making more room), and
2. without comparing the files in the desktop folder to what appears on the desktop, one by one, to find what's missing.

(The screen is already at the maximum resolution, and the existing driver doesn't have any visible options to extend the screen.  I don't know what's involved in modifying my system to have a scrollable screen.

(Regarding the possible duplicate notice, this has nothing to do with two monitors, or layouts for future use.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Save Desktop icon layout position with a different profile for one or two monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/1024607/how-to-save-desktop-icon-layout-position-with-a-different-profile-for-one-or-two)

Comment: I fear you'll have to (at least once) go through 1st and then install a tool to save your layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed a desktop-extender to solve this.  As the program is bulky and clumsy, I am not recommending the one I used.  A google search for these lists several, but I only tried one.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new folder on your desktop.
2. Open your desktop as a folder (in Windows Explorer, find "Desktop" under "This PC"). You'll see all your icons there, including those located outside the normal desktop screen.
3. Drag them to the new folder you created at step 1.
4. Drag them one by one from this new folder to your desktop to the locations you want.

Comment: That's option 1 described above.  I'm looking for a less tedious method.

Comment: Basically you want to automatically separate visible icons from those that aren't visible. I really doubt it can be done. There is no "sorting by visibility" option, so I bet most solutions will involve some manual work. What you also can try is to create a second virtual desktop, move all your visible icons there, thus you'll preserve their order. Then go back to your first desktop, press Ctr+A (select all), then cut them (Ctrl+X) and paste to another folder. Now you have your original icons on the second desktop (move them back) and invisible icons in the folder. Not sure, just a theory.